# NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI on Firefox only on localhost

Tags: firefox, localhost

I'm trying to switch to Firefox for development but I'm stuck at this error and I have no idea what it could be.

The problem is specifically with our Login endpoint, which sets HttpOnly cookies on successful login. In development this works on both Safari and Chrome, but trying to login on Firefox returns a `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI` error.

In development, web is running at `http://localhost:3000`, the API is on `https://localhost:5001`.

I assume Firefox is blocking the login because the api and the web are technically on different origins, but I don't understand why it would be doing that for localhost.

Is there a way to disable this error entirely?